# Is there a way to set the post-login landing page/url/path in Custom Portal login URL

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, customer-portal

Our company still uses the custom portal with site, we have a site page as a customised portal login page collects user email and password then redirected to portal login URL like this:

```
    PageReference p = new PageReference(https://na3.salesforce.com/secur/login_portal.jsp?orgId=00D50035445xxx&portalId=060500000000xxx&un=xxx&pw=xxx);
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
```

General speaking, I need to keep the default landing page/tab which is the `home` tab, but if an unauthorised use directly request the `report` tab's url, I want to redirect the user to login_portal first, then redirect to the  `report` tab after login.

Is there a way we can set the landing URL after login in that URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Site.Login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) with startUrl for navigating to specific url.

```
Site.login(username, password, startUrl)
```

We have implemented like below in Lightning. This is redirecting to given startURL after successful login.

```
public static String login(String username, String password, String startUrl) {
        try{
            ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
            aura.redirect(lgn);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();            
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try